# Is it necessary to control a servo with pid

Tags: arduino, pid-controller

So, I need to build a simple gimbal with three servos to control pitch, roll and yaw. I have a 9dof imu which can give me the euler angles in degrees. Can I just connect these angle errors to servo outputs? As in with 1 degree error, the servo should rotate 1 degree, or do I have to use some form of pid control? I have worked with controlling regular dc motors with pid so that the bigger the error, the faster the motor should rotate to compensate. But it's not like I can adjust the speed the servo rotates at.

I recon there would be a problem when the angle error becomes very high in a small amount of time since the servo would take more time to reach the desired position instead of when the error is very small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a similar project. It isn't perfect, but good enough. Cheap servos can't really be precise because of the cheap potentiometer inside and the horrible plastic gears.

There wont be much error overtime because common servos use a potentiometer and not a rotary encoder. Thus a PID is almost impossible.